# .Net XmlDocument can't load Access table exported as xml containing control characters

Tags: .net, xml, ms-access

The title seems a bit long but here the problem:
I have data exported from Access into an xml file (by using the GUI, right mouse on the table => Export as => xml). I want to load these xml files with .Net using the regular namespace System.Xml. Now I have ♂ char(Ascii:11) in this xml. The character is in the inner text of the tag. But it is not escaped and therefore the Load function of the XmlDocument throws an error that this is an invalid character. How to fix this in a good way? Should Access improve this? Is .Net misleading here?

I have an answer to the problem(see below) but this seems not to be a good answer.

Working Example:

```
string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?><root><tag>,- </tag></root>";
System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
```

Neither SO nor Visual Studio does display the invalid char but it should be copyable. Otherwise open in Notepad++ and insert a vertical tab as seen here:

[image: Notepad++ View]

And this is exactly data from the Access table. That entry contains the ♂ symbol in the text.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to specify **(1)** how the data is being exported from Access (e.g., `Application.ExportXML` in VBA?), and **(2)** where the control characters are appearing (e.g., as field data? If so, what type of field?).

Comment: @GordThompson I hope this is what you expect and helps to answer it.

Comment: *"The character is in the inner text of a the tag."* - Can you show us an example? Is it caused by "funny" characters in a field name?

Comment: @GordThompson I added a "working" example to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution (optimization would be a StringBuilder) but I don't like that I have to fix a Microsoft generated file to work with a Microsoft framework ...

```
string escapeControl(char c)
{
    if ((c < 32 || c == 127) && !(c == 10 || c == 13))
        return string.Format("&#{0};", (int)c);
    return c.ToString();
}

string xml = File.ReadAllText(filename, Encoding.UTF8);
xml = xml.Select((e) => escapeControl(e)).Join("");
doc.LoadXml(xml);
```